# Multiple comparison in three groups: How could I do if two groups look like significant different, but there is no statistical significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, small-sample

I have the data set that collected in three different conditions. However, the sample size is extremely different (a - 6, b - 30, and c - 6).

I examined how different conditions affect to the total. Condition did not affect significantly to total. However, after I draw plot by using this data, I realized that it looks like significantly different in a - b and a - c. So, I tested differences using t.test. The results of t.test returned significant p-value, but the results of multiple comparisons didn't have any significance in combinations.

It looks like that I may be misunderstood some fundamental statistic underlying the test, but I don't have any idea of this issue. By the way, I'm very beginner for statistic analysis.

It would be appreciated if there is any suggestions, advice, or criticism for my question.

Below is my R code for the analysis.

## there are three groups having different sample size

## letters indicate different condition

## a - 6, b - 30, c - 6

a <- data.frame("total" = c(180.3946, 184.5053, 174.7285, 176.7839, 168.2292, 171.951), "cond" = "a")

b <- data.frame("total" = c(183.4105,186.4333,178.9715,246.7047,231.7752,169.827,152.21,179.58,133.12,115.18,195.45,102.07,198.0954,242.6217,283.9676,388.9224,236.2608,210.8172,367.2511,374.014,366.124,367.2511,465.7633,396.5568,173.8551,101.9857,156.1761,171.3417,248.2407,206.0161),"cond" = "b")

c <- data.frame("total" = c(291.6284,280.7974,212.986,271.6146,276.5592,232.7643), "cond" = "c")

## combine into one data.frame

total.data <- rbind(a,b,c)

## run model to see the effect

model <- lm(total ~ cond, total.data)

anova(model)

## load library to do pairwise comparison

library(lsmeans)

lsmeans(model, pairwise~cond)

## t.test

t.test(a[,1], b[,1])

t.test(a[,1], c[,1])

t.test(b[,1], c[,1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the sample sizes are very small, differences have to be very large (see below) to be significant.  In your case, the means are 176, 234 and 261, but there is a lot of variation within each group.

In an ANOVA, "large" means that there is a lot more variation between groups than within. Try plotting the data and you will see this.  What's more, the two groups that are the 'tightest' each have only 6 cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, standard error is low within each group (2.4, 17.9, and 12.6). If sample size is small, is it better to use confidence interval rather than standard error? Plotting with CIs seemed not significant across the groups.